# Export Datatable to Excel using .Net core

Tags: excel, ajax, .net-core, datatable

I am trying to export datatable to excel. I am facing problem with Tempdata and ActionResult. I am getting the following error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () at the ExportExcelGrid() Action method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void ExportExcelGrid(DataTableAjaxPostModel dataTableAjaxPostModel)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] fileContent = null;

            fileContent = _specFinderExportFlow.ConvertToExportable(dataTableAjaxPostModel, User.Identity.Name);
            TempData["FileContent"] = fileContent;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ExportExcelGrid()
    {
        try
        {

            if (TempData["FileContent"] != null)
            {
                byte[] fileContent = (byte[])TempData["FileContent"];
                string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
                string fileDownloadName = UserConstants.EXPORT_FILE_NAME + dateTime + UserConstants.EXPORT_FILE_EXT;

                return File(fileContent, ExcelExportHelper.ExcelContentType, fileDownloadName);
            }

            else
                return null;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

And in my script I have used ajax call to get the datatable.

```
         $('#productexport').on('click', function () {
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#ExportExcelGrid").val(),
        data: findertable.ajax.params(),
        success: function (response) {
            window.location.href = $("#ExportExcelGrid").val();
        },
        failure: function (response) {
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
});
```

After ExportExcelGrid(DataTableAjaxPostModel dataTableAjaxPostModel) method ExportExcelGrid() has to be called. But it is not getting called. If I use ViewData it is null. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong.